# How to convert array of strings to array of characters in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm hoping for some help trying to convert a String[] to a char[][].
For example, given the array of strings:

`String[] example = ["aabba", "ababa", "aaaca"];`

I want it to be:

```
char[][] example = {{'a','a','b','b','a'},
                  {'a','b','a','b','a'},
                  {'a','a','a','c','a'}};
```

I'm guessing using .getChar()/.charAt() would be useful but am not sure how to loop through the String array and separate the elements..how could I go about coding this transformation?

Comment: *not sure how to loop through the String array* - not sure what you mean? You loop through a String array same way you loop through any array. The size of the array is determined by the example.length field. Then you can use the `String.toCharArray()` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static char[][] convertStringArrayToCharMultiDimension(String [] stringArray) {
    // Create the character multi-dimensional Array.
    // note that the 1st dimension is being initialized with the size of the string Array. We don't initialize the other dimension since we don't know the length of each String in the Array
    char[][] charMultiDimArray = new char[stringArray.length][];
    for (int i = 0; i  < stringArray.length; ++i) {
        charMultiDimArray[i] = stringArray[i].toCharArray();
    }

    // The length of the Multi-dimensional Array gives the length of the 1st Dimension.
    for (int i = 0; i  < charMultiDimArray.length; ++i) {
        System.out.println(charMultiDimArray[i]);
    }

    return charMultiDimArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
String[] example = {"aabba", "ababa", "aaaca"};
char[][] result = Arrays.stream(example)
    .map(s -> s.toCharArray())
    .toArray(char[][]::new);
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(result));
```

output

```
[a, a, b, b, a], [a, b, a, b, a], [a, a, a, c, a]]
```